# I quite don't understand UIPickerView

Tags: ios, sqlite, uipickerview

So, I have an App with sqliteDB, the filling it comes from App, for example Name, Lastname. Now I'm trying add a pickerview to my form, but absolutely don't know how I can work with it. 
This button processes the input data from textfield, I tried add here the same picker, but nothing happens. Perhaps, I shall write some instead of "???" ? Have tried ".dataSourse" , nothing happens.!

```
- (IBAction)saveInfo:(id)sender {
NSString *query;
if (self.recordIDToEdit == -1) {
    query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into peopleInfo values(null, '%@', '%@', '%@', '%s')", self.txtFirstname.text, self.txtLastname.text, self.txtCategory.text, self.txtPicker.???;
}
else{
    query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update peopleInfo set firstname='%@', lastname='%@', category='%@', suka='%s' where peopleInfoID=%d", self.txtFirstname.text, self.txtLastname.text, self.txtCategory.text, self.txtPicker.???, self.recordIDToEdit];
}
```

I've announced *select such a selected value, but I don't know how add it to my DB like other data from textfield..

```
    NSString *select = [_array objectAtIndex:[_txtPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]];
```

can be so do not get to add data to the database?

Comment: huh whatt ?? and where is the picker

Comment: picker matched with txtPicker by Outlet

Comment: You are trying to put a UIPicker in a string ? explain your goal please

Comment: What shall I put it in? Don't know..

Comment: The selected value from the picker perhaps, but not the picker itself!

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov why not try an online tutorial. The picker view is a little bit involved: http://codewithchris.com/uipickerview-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the selected row index from:

```
- (NSInteger)selectedRowInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
```

for example:

```
int index = [txtPickerselectedRowInComponent:0];
self.strTx= [pickerData objectAtIndex:index];
```

or using delegate:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
                      didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component;
```

basically when someone select an item from your picker, just read the value

```
 self.strTx= [pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
```

So you have the choice